# how to connect a unit number to stdin and stdout?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have overwritten the reserved UNIT NUMBER 5 and 6 to read and write files respectively. So I now cannot read `stdin` and write `stdout`.

Instead of changing all my code, I want to connect the stdin and stdout to new UNIT NUMBERS 7 and 8 respectively. How can I do that?

**EDIT#1**

Let me cite an example to clarify my situation.

```
OPEN (UNIT=5, FILE='input.txt', status='OLD')
OPEN (UNIT=6, FILE='output.txt', status='REPLACE')
...some code...
READ (5, *format1*) x, y, z
WRITE (6, *format2*) i, j ,k
```

The original code is not written by me and is of about 4000 lines. Since I am new to fortran77 so i don't want to modify the `OPEN` statement as I am worried that this will lead to more problems for me to solve. If reconnecting the `stdin` and `stdout` to a new UNIT NUMBER is possible, it will keep me away from many potential troubles.

**Edit#2**

Please read my question clearly. My question is how to do that. I am not concerning whether it is good to do that. If it is impossible to do that, it is also a valid answer to me and can prevent other people to repeat the same question. Thank you all.

Comment: Why you need that? Try to use named variables wherever possible.

Comment: @VladimirF What do you mean about named variables?

Comment: I mean to change the hardwired values 5 and 6 to some variables you can control and change. 4000 lines is actually not a very large program.

Comment: Reconnecting `stdin` and `stdout` to other unit numbers is just compounding the problem, even if it is achievable.  Bite the bullet and modify the source.

Comment: I have modified the source code. But can someone finally tell me if I can do the re-connection in fortran 77?

Comment: I have read your question clearly, and based on his track record here on SO I believe that @VladimirF has too.  I have already told you I don't think that you can do what you want to achieve, and no one has gainsaid me yet.  But don't come here and get all snippy when you get, alongside an answer, some good advice.  If you don't like the advice, ignore it.

Comment: It is always easier to prove the existence of something than to prove unexistence of something. As I see both of you are lack of confidence to ascertain there is no way to do it. So I try to redirect the discussion back to the question again. Really no offence. And I seem to find the answer. Check it out below.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gfortran, you may try to set the environment variables GFORTRAN_STDIN_UNIT and GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT to select the unit number to pre-connect to `stdin` and `stdout` respectively.

Details can be found in this document:

[gfortran.pdf](http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~serra/gfortran.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered `5` and `6` aren't reserved at all, they're just the units which are usually pre-connected to `stdin` and `stdout` on Unix-like operating systems.  I don't believe that there is a language-standard and portable way of connecting other units to those pseudo-files.  I also believe that by stating my lack of belief I will draw out someone who does know how to do what you want.  We'll see.

In the meantime, if you are using the Intel Fortran compiler you can redirect output sent to a file, or input drawn from a file, by setting values for the environment variables `FOR_PRINT` and `FOR_READ`.  Check the compiler documentation for details.

Finally, I don't understand how you have got to the situation where you need to do what you seem to think you need to do.  Surely a global search and replace with a good editor will fix the problem ?  Even more confusing, to me, is that if you have opened files on units `5` and `6` surely you can just modify a few `open` statements ?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution shows the reconnection on linux, where the pseudo-files `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` can be found. As these files are not available on Windows, this is an *unportable* solution.

In case, you want to develop for linux, you can simply open these files with your preferred units (preferably with named variables, as @VladimirF pointed out). Though, I'm not sure, if the following code is compatible with Fortran77 (do you actually need Fortran77?).

```
program test

    integer :: stdin, stdout, a

    ! open the files
    open(7, file="/dev/stdout", status="old")
    open(8, file="/dev/stdin", status="old")

    ! read and write an integer from/to the terminal
    read(7,*) a
    write(8,*) a
end program
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I use windows. But it is still a good answer for those using linux.